# Rest Webservice returning http status 404

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am using Apache Tomcat 6 and the Jersey 2.0 libraries. I am running this service on 8088 port. While trying to access it, getting 404 not found error. This is my service:

**User Class**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;  

import java.io.Serializable;  
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement; 
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement; 
@XmlRootElement(name = "user") 

public class User implements Serializable {  
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
   private int id; 
   private String name; 
   private String profession;  
   public User(){} 

   public User(int id, String name, String profession){  
      this.id = id; 
      this.name = name; 
      this.profession = profession; 
   }  
   public int getId() { 
      return id; 
   }  
   @XmlElement 
   public void setId(int id) { 
      this.id = id; 
   } 
   public String getName() { 
      return name; 
   } 
   @XmlElement
   public void setName(String name) { 
      this.name = name; 
   } 
   public String getProfession() { 
      return profession; 
   } 
   @XmlElement 
   public void setProfession(String profession) { 
      this.profession = profession; 
   }   
}
```

**UserDao Class**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;  

import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileInputStream; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.ObjectInputStream; 
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.List;  

public class UserDao { 
   public List<User> getAllUsers(int id){ 

      List<User> userList = null; 
      try {
             User user = null;
             if(id == 1){
                 user = new User(1, "Mahesh", "Teacher"); 
             }
             if(id == 2){
                 user = new User(2, "Manish", "Doctor"); 
             }
             userList = new ArrayList<User>(); 
             userList.add(user); 

      } catch (Exception e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }   
      return userList; 
   }  
}
```

**UserService class**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;  

import java.util.List; 
import javax.ws.rs.GET; 
import javax.ws.rs.Path; 
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces; 
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;  
@Path("/UserService") 

public class UserService {  
   UserDao userDao = new UserDao();  
   @GET 
   @Path("{id}") 
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   public List<User> getUsers(@PathParam("id") int id){ 
      return userDao.getAllUsers(id); 
   }  
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?> 
<web-app xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
   xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"  
   id = "WebApp_ID" version = "3.0"> 
   <display-name>UserManagement</display-name> 
   <servlet> 
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> 

   </servlet> 
   <servlet-mapping> 
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern> 
   </servlet-mapping>   
</web-app>
```

[My project Stucture is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rhzE.png)

[Getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3tmn.png)

Comment: Please share the path that you are accessing

Comment: Path of tutorial or what?

Comment: http://localhost:8088/UserManagement/rest/UserService/1